# 2006 Honda Civic Won't Start - Green Key Symbol

Tags: starting

My 2006 Honda Civic does not start in the morning. It is showing a green key sign on the dash board, which makes to suspect the key immobiliser. It will start in the afternoon when sun has hit it well. The battery and the starter are good. I live in warm climate, so it is not cold. What could the cause be?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The green key sign IS the indication the immobilizer is activated. Check out [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/8647/4939) to a similar question. It may help provide some answers for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in suspecting the immobilizer (with the flashing green key), but before tinkering with the immobilizer itself, check 2 things:

- **is your key the issue?** Chip keys and transponder keys get worn out. While the key may be mechanically fine, sometimes the chip gets partially disconnected. If you have a spare chip key for this vehicle, try it. Also, some transponder keys have batteries inside them, so replace yours if you have one. You may also want to remove the key from your keyring, most people have way too many things on there and it's pulling the keys and the ignition down, and possibly interfering with the immobilizer seeing the key.
- **tried the remote start?** Immobilizers prevent you from driving the car without a legit key, but you should still be able to start the car with the remote. You won't be able to drive it without the immobilizer seeing your key, but this will rule out a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some data about your immobilizer system, hope it helps. Not sure if there is a battery in the key or not, if it does have a battery it may be dead and need replaced.

[image]

[image]